# Tableau Ask Data Service Will Not Start and Cannot Find Log File Location

Tags: tableau-api

When starting the Tableau service (v2020.4), the Ask Data service fails to start.  The logs for these services are supposed to be "C:\ProgramData\Tableau\Tableau Server\data\tabsvc\logs", but I have no clue what folder corresponds to the "Ask Data" service to find out what is causing the service to fail.  Within that location, there are many folders.  Does anyone know where the logs are located for this service?